Use Firestore in both Flutter module and native iOS
We have a native iOS app and we're migrating it to Flutter incrementally as rewriting the entire app in Flutter is not viable at the moment. We heavily depend upon Firebase resources, such as auth, Firestore, etc. and we need to use them both in native code and Flutter code.
We were able to initialize the Firebase instance in Flutter:
final app = await Firebase.initializeApp();

As well as get the current user, which was authenticated by the native code, from Firebase auth:
final userId = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser?.uid;

However, we are not able to access Firestore:
final users = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').get();

Whenever we try that, we get an error:

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'FIRIllegalStateException', reason: 'Firestore instance has already been started and its settings can no longer be changed. You can only set settings before calling any other methods on a Firestore instance.'

It seems the FLTFirebaseFirestorePlugin is trying to redefine the settings of the current Firestore instance:
FIRFirestore *firestore = [FIRFirestore firestoreForApp:app database:databaseUrl];
firestore.settings = settings;

We tried many things but can't get past that error.
Has anyone been able to use Firestore in both Flutter module and native iOS?
Or is there any workaround that could be applied?

Found the exact same issue here, with no response: Initialize and use Firestore in both native iOS and Flutter
Also reported in this GH ticket: https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/issues/9582

Looks like Firebase and Firestore have already created an App instance named DEFAULT on the iOS native side, and cannot recreate a new Firestore instance when you call FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').get();
I suggest you create another instance in Flutter by passing a name variable by initializing Firebase in Flutter like this:
final app = await Firebase.initializeApp(name: "ANOTHER_INSTANCE");

Thanks for your response! We've already tried that, but it doesn't work. The Firebase app is initialized, but Firestore on Flutter side doesn't share authentication state with the native side, so we get permission denied due to reading rules on Firestore collections.

I did some research and I came up with this flow;


Remove the platform (iOS) initialization and only initialize the app in Flutter. This will automatically create a default instance on iOS. FlutterFire plugins use Method Channel and depend on the platform code, so this pattern will initialize a default app on the platform side too.


Now, log in the user on the platform side (iOS) without initializing the app again, then call await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser?.reload(); on Flutter and try to access read from Firestore from Flutter again.



Actually, the permission denied we were getting on the Firestore collections was right. Our query was targeting the wrong path. Once we fixed it, it worked! So it seems the only requirement was indeed setting a different app name for the Firebase instance other than the default one.
